# Drag and drop a file into application window using WPF and data binding

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding, drag-and-drop

I'd like to be able to drag and drop a file (e.g. from Desktop or Explorer) right into the main window of a WPF application.

I also want no code behind, i.e. I want to use data binding.

So far I tested the "gong-wpf-dragdrop" which doesn't seem to support drag targets outside the application.

I could drop a file to the main window and the drag and drop events fired - but the data was empty (dragged a non-empty text file).

EDIT: gong-wpf-dragdrop works (after a small fix) and the problem also occurred when using code behind.

So the complete solution was to use gong wpf ([github](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop)) and the solution presented by Omribitan.

Comment: Have you tried [GetFileDropList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataobject.getfiledroplist.aspx) method? you can retreive it from the `e.Data` in the [Drop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.drop.aspx) event. Something like `string filename = (string)((DataObject)e.Data).GetFileDropList()[0]`

Comment: This did the trick! If you add it as an answer, I can marked it solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

have you tried [GetFileDropList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataobject.getfiledroplist.aspx) method? you can retreive it from the e.Data in the [Drop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.drop.aspx) event.

Something like:

```
string filename = (string)((DataObject)e.Data).GetFileDropList()[0];
```