# drag and drop Outlook attachment from Outlook in to a WPF datagrid

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, outlook

I saw this code ealier about drag and dropping attachment files (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C) from Outlook into Windows Form and it works fine in windows Forms, but I can't seem to make it work with WPF.
I tried to simply change System.windows.form.IDataObject to System.Windows.IDataObject but it doesn't work (as I should have guessed).

I also simply tried to get the content of the e.Data FileContents but always get errors (which seems to be the case to everyone when I check on the web).

Did anyone ever did drag and dropping attachment from Outlook to WPF ? I am at a complete loss.

Edit : I am not trying to get file from a Windows Explorer windows ( I do but I know how to). It's really the whole getting attachment from Outlook directly that doesn't work . I am fully aware too that I could simple take the file from outlook into a temp folder and then drop it into my program, but I would like to avoid this unncessary step if possible.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to drag into and did you set that control's AllowDrop property to true?

Comment: I want to drag attach files (any file) from an email and yes, I set the AllowDrop to true. I can easily get the filenames (although it does come off in a weird format), but I can't get the content. When I try to get the filecontent, I get an error. I can't use the link I put in this email because it's Windows.Form and it won't translate easily from Forms.IDataObject to IDataObject

Comment: That was an important point you didn't mention so in that case my answer below is not relevant and will be deleted...

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19356097/229930

Comment: @DeanK. That only workds with file from Explorer. This I can easily manage. It's when it's coming from Outlook that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so in the end I was able to find out a link where someone did exactly that :

https://gist.github.com/MattyBoy4444/521547

For those who wonders. Here is what I did exactly.

- Create a new project in C# (my code is in VB) and add the code to it
- Reference the new project in my main project to be able to use it
- In my drop Event, check whether or not I had the "FileGroupDescriptorW" object in the drop data and called the method if I do to retrieve the files.

Here is the complete code

```
If obj.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptorW") Then 'Outlook
    Dim oOutLookObj As New Helpers.OutlookDataObject(e.Data)
    Dim StrFiles() As String = oOutLookObj.GetData("FileGroupDescriptorW")
    Dim contentStream() As System.IO.MemoryStream = oOutLookObj.GetData("FileContents")
    ' Do intended work...
End if
```

The names of the files are in StrFiles and the content are found in the streams. Both have the same array size and are order correctly.

Comment: What about drag from WPF application and drop to Outlook Email ? is it working also & how ?

Comment: @Sachin : This does not handle from WPF to Outlook, just from Outlook to WPF.